# Speeding Up Sparse Matrix Generalized Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues, sparse-arrays

I have a generalized eigenvalue problem
$$
{\mathbf A}\vec v = \lambda {\mathbf B} \vec v
$$
for which I am trying to find the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda$ and the associated eigenvector $\vec v$. Note that ${\mathbf A}$ and ${\mathbf B}$ are both sparse (they are $N\times N$ but contain ${\mathcal O}(N)$ non-zero entries). I then use the following function to find the smallest magnitude eigenvalue and associated eigenvectors
$$
\{{\lambda,v}\} = {\texttt{Eigensystem[{A, B}, -1]}}\,.
$$
This works great when ${\mathbf A}$ and ${\mathbf B}$, which are both defined as $\texttt{SparseArray}$ objects, are smaller than about $600\times 600$, but becomes extremely slow when the matrices become marginally bigger. Clearly I am doing something wrong, because the same code runs in matlab in a fraction of a second for much bigger matrices.

How can I speed up this computation? Are there options I have neglected to set correctly? Is there another function I should be using?

Here is an example problem that exhibits the same behavior

```
Clear["Global`*"]
GridSize = 500;
dx = 0.1;
ones = Table[1, {ii, 1, GridSize}];
DL = 1/dx^2 ones;
DL = Drop[DL, -1];
DM = -(2/dx^2) ones;
DR = DL;
RHS = ones;
RHS[[-1]] = 0;
A = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> DL, Band[{1, 1}] -> DM, 
    Band[{2, 1}] -> DR}, {GridSize, GridSize}];
B = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> RHS}, {GridSize, GridSize}];

EV = Eigensystem[{A, B}, -1];
```

Comment: How are `A` and `B` defined? Are they actually `SparseArray` objects? Can you give an example?

Comment: I am trying to think of a good example that isn't the actual problem I'm working with, but yes they are defined as sparse-array objects.

Comment: @LukasLang I've included an example. What makes this problem slow is the non-invertability of B.

Comment: “Clearly I am doing something wrong” Not necessarily. Unlike the usual eigenvalue problem, there doesn't exist an efficient algorithm for **generalized** eigenvalue problem AFAIK. I sincerely hope I'm wrong.

Comment: @xzczd I see - I wonder how matlab manages to do it so well! Perhaps it's through some clever parallelization? Is parallelism in Eigensystem possible in mathematica?

Comment: You mean MATLAB solves **exactly** the same problem efficiently? If so, it's a bit wield then. For linear algebra, MATLAB and Mathematica uses the same library under the hood AFAIK. Can you add the corresponding MATLAB code and testing result to your question?

Comment: `DRL` is not defined.

Comment: @BobHanlon Oops - fixed.

Comment: @xzczd I'll make an example matlab code hopefully tomorrow. For comparison, matlab has no trouble finding the smallest eigenvalue of a much more complicated generalized eigenvalue problem of size 10^5 x 10^5 or so (takes about 0.2 seconds on my old computer that still has matlab installed). I'll also add that the eigenvalues I find on mathematica are wrong (checking against well-known values in the literature), although I have gone through element-wise and checked that both my matlab and mathematica code are solving the same system.

Comment: I'll add that the "wrongness" of the mathematica solution is tiny, on the order of 10^-11, but unfortunately that's the part of the eigenvalue I care about.

Comment: @xzczd "For linear algebra, MATLAB and Mathematica uses the same library under the hood AFAIK." This is very true in general. They both use the Intel MKL on x86 processors. But I think to remember that some guys from WR once told me on this site that the eigensolvers where home baked. And btw., working now with an Apple M1, I can say that _Mathematica_ does _not_ use MKL there (because it runs "natively"). I know that very well, because I am deeply missing Intel Pardiso. (sniff) But Matlab still requires MKL (and thus is run through the x86 compatibility mode Rosetta 2).

Comment: If your matrix $A$ is really tridiagonal and the matrix $B$ is diagonal (as in your example), you can simply form $B^{-1} A$ which is again tridiagonal. T

Comment: ridiagonal is of interest because taking the input matrix to tridiagonal fotm (or more general: to Hessenberg form) is the preprocessing step of the QR agorithm for computing eigenpairs -- which is not to be confused with the QR factorization (the latter is the key ingredient for the former, though). So that would problaby quite an "easy" generalized eigenvalue problem. But I am pretty sure your example is not really characteristic for your actual problem.

Comment: Btw.: If $B^{-1} A$ is really tridiagonal, then the action of its inverse on a vector can be computed very efficiently by using the Thomas algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm. And for matrices whose inverse action can be computed efficiently, the smallest eigenvalue can be computed by inverse power iterations (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_iteration).

Answer (score 3):

Since you seek a numerical result and your matrices are machine-precision, you can use the Arnoldi method, which is optimized to find only some eigenvalues. You also ask specifically for eigenvalues, so you could use Eigenvalues rather than Eigensystem:

```
GridSize = 100000;

dx = 0.1;
ones = Table[1, {ii, 1, GridSize}];
DL = 1/dx^2 ones;
DL = Drop[DL, -1];
DM = -(2/dx^2) ones;
DR = DL;
RHS = ones;
RHS[[-1]] = 0;
A = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> DL, Band[{1, 1}] -> DM, Band[{2, 1}] -> DR}, {GridSize, GridSize}];
B = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> RHS}, {GridSize, GridSize}];

EV = Eigenvalues[{A, B}, -1, Method -> "Arnoldi"]

(* Out: {-9.86941*10^-8} *)
```

Timing indicates that the calculation does indeed take a fraction of a second even for a grid size of $100 000\times100000$ in MMA as well:

```
RepeatedTiming[Eigenvalues[{A, B}, -1, Method -> "Arnoldi"];]

(* Out: {0.621861, Null} *)
```

These calculations are done at machine precision, which would be the default in Matlab. If you think you need more precision, you can change the definition of `dx` to include an arbitrary precision specification, e.g. `` dx = 0.1`10 `` to carry out calculations with 10 digits of precision. This will inevitably be much slower and, in this case, it did not change the result when I tried it. It would be helpful if you could add to your question what you expect the result to be.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I suppose my simplified example failed to capture some of the key features of my problem. In particular, my matrix is non-hermitian, so arnoldi doesn't work. I'll work out a better non-hermitian example problem and put it in the main question.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to embed a non-hermitian operator in a larger space where it is hermitian? Sounds unlikely but maybe that's what matlab is doing?

Comment: @Guy I don't think the Arnoldi method requires its input to be Hermitian. Consider: `a = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 3}, {2, 1, 0}}; HermitianMatrixQ[a]` returns False, and yet `Eigenvalues[N@a, 1, Method -> "Arnoldi"]` works fine. The input must be either machine-precision, or of finite arbitrary precision though (which you could achieve with `N` or `SetPrecision`).

Comment: Interesting - it doesn't seem to work for a generalized eigenvalue problem though. For instance ```a = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 3}, {2, 1, 0}};
b = {{1, 1, 3}, {2, 5, 3}, {4, 1, 0}}; Eigenvalues[{N@a, N@b}, 1, Method -> "Arnoldi"]``` leads to the output ```Eigenvalues::herm: The matrix {{1.,1.,3.},{2.,5.,3.},{4.,1.,0.}} is not Hermitian or real and symmetric.```